# Что может храниться в стеке, а что в куче?

Tags: c#

### Верно ли я понял, что где может храниться?

Я так понял, что ***в стеке*** хранятся:

- Структуры с полями (поля типа значения - в стеке, а поля ссылочного типа - в куче с ссылкой на них в стеке)
- Ссылки на объекты в куче

А ***в куче*** хранятся:

- Классы с полями и ссылочного, и значимого типа
- Массивы с элементами и ссылочного, и значимого типа
- Статические поля и ссылочного, и значимого типа

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, на какую глубину в кроличью нору вы готовы провалиться. Для уровня джуна достаточно упрощённого понимания что значимые типы хранятся в стеке, а ссылочные - в куче. Если хочется подробнее... ну вот тут было например: https://habr.com/ru/post/541786/ И вы в вопросе создали сразу пять примеров - это в общем-то пять разных вопросов, по-хорошему выбрали бы что-то одно характерное.

Comment: Верно поняли. Но это если не залезать в детали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куча в C# — это надстройка над неуправляемой кучей. Её так называют, т.к. там память нужно освобождать вручную (или ждать конца выполнения процесса), в отличие от C#, где память освобождает сборщик мусора (GC).

В C# создали разделение на структуры и классы для оптимизации: классы можно хранить только в куче, а структуры — и там и там. Если вы хотите хранить структуру в куче, вы должны её обернуть ([boxing](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)) в объект типа `object` или реализуемый структурой интерфейс. Пример:

```cs
public struct MyStruct : IMyInterface // `IMyInterface` - реализуемый интерфейс
{
    // ...
}
```

```cs
MyStruct @struct = default;
var boxed = (object)@struct; // упаковка в `object`
var @interface = (IMyInterface)@struct; // упаковка в `IMyInterface`
```

Про [`GCHandle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle), [`Marshal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal) и проч. я рассказывать не буду, т.к. это работа с неуправляемой памятью, что относительно сложно.

Вы также в своём вопросе написали:

> А *в куче* хранятся ... статические поля и ссылочного, и значимого типа.

Это не совсем так. В процессе (в классическом представлении) есть 4 отдела (или, как правильно, сегмента) для хранения памяти:

- Куча
- Стек
- Константы
- Статическая память

Куча общая, стек — память каждого потока. Память под константы и статическая память идентичны, за одним исключением: константы неизменяемы. Там обычно хранятся большие данные, а маленькие константы (по типу `int`) просто подставляются (inlining) в то место, где они нужны. Статические данные же изменяемы. Т.е. статические структуры/константы хранятся либо в специальном для этого отделе, либо подставляются.

В данных констант хранятся также строки и массивы с константными данными.

Но вообще, всё это делали реализации и вам не сильно важно, где эти данные хранятся: память в C# управляемая и то, где вы будете хранить данные, выбирает компилятор, давая в некоторых местах свободу действий.